# Problemas ao usar o elemento CardView (Material Design - Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, gradle, material-design

Estou tentando **usar o elemento CardView do Material Design** no meu app Android, mas não estou conseguindo.

**Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar o erro do meu código?**

Segue abaixo o código utilizado.

**Log do Android Studio**

```
2020-07-21 17:03:36.343 25309-25309/com.pokemon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pokemon, PID: 25309
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pokemon/com.pokemon.View.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1976)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.pokemon.View.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7148)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7139)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1976)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pokemon"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".View.MainActivity">

                <!-- POKEMON CARD -->
  <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="180dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/backgroundColor"
      app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
      >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:text="@string/pokemon_name"
          android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:text="@string/pokemon_description"
          android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.pokemon.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;

import com.pokemon.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pokemon">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_pokebola1_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity android:name=".View.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".View.MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi porque o pacote do tema do Material Design que eu estava utilizando no arquivo do styles.xml
*"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"*
não possuía o elemento CardView

Resolvi o problema:

1. Criando um tema específico para a minha tela inicial e um tema
   padrão    para o app;
2. Adicionando a propriedade `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` no    elemento raiz da tela do CardView;
3. E modifiquei o código do arquivo activity_main com um código que    mostra um layout diferente de CardView do que estava utilizando
   anteriormente.

**Alterei os arquivos styles.xml e activity_main.xml**

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Splash Screen Theme -->
    <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:context=".View.MainActivity">

                <!-- POKEMON CARD -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Media -->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_pokemon"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/pokemon_description"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <!-- Title, secondary and supporting text -->
                  <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="@string/title_pokemon_name"
                      android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                      />

                  <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/pokemon_description"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```